# Can't set webhook to viber bot

Tags: web, postman, webhooks, viber-api, viber-bot

I have some troubles with setting webhook to my viber bot. Every time I wanna set my url viber api returns error.
So I am trying to use this in postman:

Url: `https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook`

```
{
    "url": "https://gutapi.ml/api/viber/post",
    "event_types":[
      "conversation_started"
   ]
}
```

When I use code below, viber api returns this result:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "chat_hostname": "SN-CHAT-06_"
}
```

My url is valid and I have ssl sertificate, but it still does not work. Hope you'll help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Http error: "500 (Internal Server Error)" on any post request. So problem is on your side :)

Try to send POST request to https://gutapi.ml/api/viber/post (your server) with following payload using Postman and look to your logs.

```json
{
   "status":0,
   "status_message":"ok",
   "event_types":[
      "conversation_started"
   ]
}
```

Also have a look to [Viber API documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#setting-a-webhook) for more details:

Comment: This not actual anymore